# Is it possible to copy/yank everything until a matching word is found?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Say I have a text like

```
...

def my_function() do
...
end

...
```

And I want to yank/copy from `def` to `end` (including both `def` and `end`), so I can paste this block of text elsewhere.

Is it possible to that in vim? If so, how would I go about it?

I know that with the command `yt[character]` you can copy everything until the character is found, but in this case, I need to copy until `end` is found.

Also, it would be nice to be able to a regex to specify when to stop copying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a search with `/` or `?` as a motion for a `y` operation. But that can be tricky, because the search motion will be characterwise and exclusive.

So if you position your cursor at the `d` in `def` and then use `y/end<Return>` (where `<Return>` means pressing the <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> key), Vim will copy everything until the beginning of `end` *except* for the word `end` itself.

One way you can fix this is by using a `/e` modifier on the search, which will position the cursor at the end of the match and serve to include the word, so using `y/end/e<Return>` works here. You end up yanking what you originally wanted, but the yank is still characterwise, meaning it won't include a newline at the end, and if you put it at the middle of a line, it will start putting it right at the cursor position, not before or after the line. (See [`:help search-offset`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#search-offset) for more details on the `/e` modifier.)

If you want to yank the block linewise, then you can use `V` as a modifier to the operation. This will turn the motion from characterwise to linewise. In that case, you no longer need the `/e` modifier, since it's using the motion to find the last line and not necessarily the character or column in that line to end the block. Using a linewise modifier also means you can be anywhere on the initial line and it will include the whole line. To use the `V` modifier, simply use `yV/end<Return>`. (See [`:help o_V`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#o_V) for more details on using `V` as an operator modifier.)

Comment: This is a wonderful answer, very complete. By pure chance I've stumbled upon `y/end/0`, I believe it would have the same effect of using `V` modifier, right?

Comment: @Quasímodo Yes, because adding an `/{offset}` at the end makes the motion linewise! `:help search-commands` documents that. It turns out that using `/e` is a little different from that, it doesn't make it linewise, but inclusive, `:help search-offset` documents that part... I really like `o_V` in that it's universal and can be applied to essentially any motion! (also `o_v` which can turn a motion into characterwise *or* change it from inclusive to exclusive or vice-versa if already characterwise.)

Answer (score 0):

Another option that is automatically linewise and only requires your cursor be somewhere in the block is

```
:?def?;/end/yank
```

Which reads « yank from the previous line containing def to the line following that containing end ».

A comma `,` instead of semicolon`;` will also work inside the block. However, if you are outside the block, a semicolon is more effective (since it makes the next part of the range relative to the start). In the outside case, you just have to adjust the `def` part to get you to the def. That could be via line number, relative offset, or forward or backward search, or even a mark.

Note that, like the other answer, if there’s an `end` in the block before the one you want, this won’t work. In that case, it may be better to get matchpairs working and use

```
[go to def]yV%
```